# VirtualBox - How easy is it to export Ubuntu VDI to raw partitions

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, vdi

I would like to ask how easy is it to export an Ubuntu VDI in VirtualBox to raw partitions and make them boot natively with the boot menu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty straight forward. Boot the virtual using [clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org) and copy the VDI data to a file.  Then from outside the virtual use clonezilla to write it to a physical disk.